# illustrator trim vectors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, pathfinder

[image]
it looks fine arent they?
[image]
it has more than one dot within a place, which bothers me too much. (i separated that very dot in this picture)
this was done by pathfinder merge and such however. any way to trim it all?

Comment: Do you have leave the "Remove Redundant Points" option checked in pathfinder options? BTW you could improve the question a bit reading the body does not reveal you mean pathfinder i need to use tags to figure this out.

Comment: In [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84505/84899) to a similar question I've made a script which should do the trick. I call the issue "split points". The script merges these points, removes any stray points and joins paths with overlapping points.