# Adobe Illustrator merge anchors by distance to clean up vectors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, anchor-point, merge

is there a way to merge anchor based on a distance? Blender has a mesh clean up command that allows it to eliminate points that have a small distance between them. Does Illustrator have something similar, or Inkscape? Here are some images illustrating two scenarios where something that executes a "merge or 'collapse' by distance" would be useful.[image: example merge anchors1]

[image: example merge anchors2]

Comment: No, but i think i saw that there was a script floating around that did this. Its not terribly hard to make but the scripting API isnt very conductive for this kind of stuff. You can do the first example with simplification though.

Comment: For the first case read [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/59032/from-a-cad-model-to-an-illustration-drawing-how-to/59071#59071)

Comment: The title of your question reminds me of [this script I wrote](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84505/84899). I don't think you can use it as it is but perhaps it can inspire. 

Comment: AI's **Smooth Tool** may help - the tool can be more controlled than the Simplify menu command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extetion what can do that for you http://cutlings.wasbo.net/remove-duplicate-nodes/

Answer (score 0):

Some non-automatic methods:

In Inkscape you simply delete a node and Inkscape redraws the path as well  as possible with the reduced number of nodes. It doesn't work in Illustrator.

The 3 double point case is different. I guess you want to convert the long and narrow area surrounded by a closed path to an equally long open path. That also needs manual crafting. You must open the paths in the visual endpoints and delete one of the separated paths.

In theory you can get literally what's asked by applying the offset path effect in Illustrator to the 3 double point case, but I guess it's only asked, not wanted. It would still be a closed path.