# Illustrator: I need an 'Average points by distance' script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, illustrator-scripting

I'm currently working on a path that was once a pattern with multiple loose ends. I'm unable to pathfinder>unite it since it's a "lines only" shape.

[image: Image of the path]

[image: Close up of the open mess]

As you can see, it's a very complex path with many many anchor points, and trying to join/average them manually using the alt+ctrl+j command would take me hours. I was hoping to find a script online that could tell illustrator to join/average by distance, similar to what Blender has for its vertices, in the hopes to cleanup this paths a little bit.

Comment: Bring it to blender cleanup bring back to illustrator? But yes the illustrator scripting layer would be incredibly slow for something like this.

Comment: [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84505/84899) I wrote is related. Perhaps you can tweak the script to fit your needs? But yeah, it would have weak performance in this case.

Comment: Must it all remains strokes? Wondering... increase stroke weight. Expand, unite, add white stroke, expand, merge, delete white. But then you're left with shapes, not strokes.

Comment: You could also ask yourself if such a cleanup is even necessary? Perhaps the gaps aren't visible at the size you'll use the pattern.

Comment: @Wolff I'm trying to make it as clean as possible, since this will be the guide for a laser cut.